# Symfony2 - Prevent a form input from displaying

Tags: symfony

I created two entities User (that contains email, password, username) and Profile(avatar...)

in the UserType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('username')
        ->add('password', 'password')
        ->add('email', 'email')
    ;
}
```

and in the ProfileType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('avatar')
        ->add('city')
        ->add('country', 'country')
        ->add('firstName')
        ->add('lastName')
        ->add('address')
        ->add('mobile')
        ->add('phone')
        ->add('user', new UserType($this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()))
    ;
}
```

Is there is a way to not display the password in the profile when the user want to edit his/her infos ?

PS: Is it a great way to separate the User entity from the Profile ?

Answer (score 1):

You  can achieve this via `FormEvents`. Something like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $user = $this->user;

    $builder
        ->add('username')
        ->add('password', 'password')
        ->add('email', 'email');

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent, $event) use ($user){
        $data = $event->getData(); // NULL or an instance of User object

        if ( $data && $data->getId() == $user->getId()){
            $event->getForm()->remove('password');
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to read more about dynamic forms, you could kind a lot of information in [**official docs**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html).